# Weird sound from a used GPU i bought. Might be a PSU thing?

Tags: windows-7, boot, power-supply, gpu

https://youtu.be/ZRnEYppzEC8

I have a 600W PSU, a N680GTX MSI Twin Frozr 3 and a Sabertooth P67 MB. In addition to this, I have 2 SSD's (one which is empty) and a 1TB HD.

Before I bought this used GPU, I had some issues with the hard drives. The computer wanted to boot up in the empty SSD, and was often not able to find the SSD with Windows on it. I had to boot up like 2-3 times to find the Windows SSD, and boot via boot menu in windows for it. I used AHCI, because IDE gave a bluescreen. Also, the PC started to boot right up again after a shutdown from Windows 7, so I had to shut it down when it powered up.

Anyways, when I plugged in the GPU, the flickering with the blue power light started, as you can see in the video. It also kept on going when I tried booting the system without the GPU.

Any ideas?

Comment: lol how many "delta" fans are in there :-) It that all RPM noise or is it dragging hitting something?  First thing i thought was somebody forgot the thermal goop on the GPU.  the cooler is there and good, but chip is heating up without any real work being tossed at it yet, because of limited thermal contact. GPU temp check would be handy, but if is working that hard, it might not make it to getting temps.

Comment: Well, read my other comment! Maybe I failed with the thermal paste, but I did had it on when I made the video. Perhaps I havent pressed the cooler tight enough onto the GPU?

Comment: If it is that badly thermal connected (everyone gets a chance to fail and learn)  I have to wonder about the VRM (voltage regulators) and the Very important Ram cooling, which is often badly done from factory.  If that all is not thermally correct too, your problems wont end here.  (better to know now, then regret later).  The state of any thermal pads, and thermal connection to all the other hot bodies on the board.

Comment: The thermal pads and the heatsink has been disconnected from the GPU for some time. Should I replace the thermal pads? I am going to try with a new PSU just to rule out that one today..

Comment: probably you should get thermal pads of either varing size and great quality or know the exact ones needed. And to also get good thermal goop and to apply it proper (once) .  done really well an operational card could last another 4-5 years, with just dust maintance.  Then you have to analise the seating , possibly even have to mount the gpu aspect of it once, to see how it is mating.  I assume this cooler came with the card originally, ones that are 3rd party can require some extra crafting to insure good gpu to heat sink seating, and care with the thermal pads and placement and all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31749/discussion-between-2013us10-and-psycogeek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little update: It was the PSU's fault. I changed it, and the computer runs smoothly now.

edit: the SSD situation was due to a bug, which the firmware eradicated.